# Why Greek yogurt has higher protein concentration?

Tags: food-chemistry, proteins

During fermentation, no nitrogen is added and the number of amino acid molecules cannot increase. Why does it have a higher protein concentration than milk?

Comment: It has less water than the original milk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because it's condensed . so it's normal for Greek yogurt to have a bigger percentage of protein than ordinary yogurt and milk .

the content of protein is the same but when we do concentration, the percentage of total solids (including protein) becomes higher.